# Bookmarkable GET link with Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, express, get

I have a website that uses Express to serve pages. Currently it works fine with a form that uses a POST query to populate the page with data, ajax-style.

I'd like the page and its contents to be bookmarkable, so I'm trying to convert this to GET. However I'm running into this problem:

The GET form works fine if I load the root page, fill out the form, and submit. However if I use the bookmark, all I get is the object as plain text.

I understand why this is happening. I don't understand what the right thing to do is to fix it. It doesn't appear that I can send both index.html and the object at the same time.

My server code:

```
app.get("/", function (request, response) {     
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.post("/formpg", main);

app.get("/formpg", main);

function main(request, response) {
  var params = request.query;
  // * and a miracle occurs *
  response.send({data:miracle});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly formed, but if I understand it you have a bookmark to the same place as the form submit occurs (**/formpg**): this will obviously return the same data the form post returns, which is the raw json (or the object as plain text).

What you're going to need to do is make the bookmark point to **/?param1=xxxx&param2=xxxxx** so it loads the HTML page, and then either parse the request query and inject the appropriate data into the page, or use JS in the **views/index.html** page to autosubmit the form with the fields populated.

Comment: How do I inject the data into index.html? I'm not a web developer.